# In C# Creating DBF Using OLEDB for dBASE IV Crashes

Tags: c#, oledb, dbf, dbase

My code is below, any time I run the unit test (or actual application) for this it just stops executing the test (despite having the code below wrapped in a try catch and a break point in the catch).

The resulting file has a field for Severity and Message, but no other fields.  I have seen this run intermittently, however, I cannot seem to get it working again.

```
//DBF Create Table
var currentLogTime = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyMMddHH");
protected const string FORMAT_CONNECTION_STRING = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=dBASE IV";
var connectionString = String.Format(FORMAT_CONNECTION_STRING, DBFPath);
Connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
Connection.Open();
using (var command = Connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText =
        String.Format(
            "CREATE TABLE {0} ([SEVERITY] NUMERIC, [MESSAGE] MEMO, [STACKTRACE] MEMO, [OCCURRED] CHAR(50))",
            currentLogTime);
    try
    {
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: well what kind of errors are you getting number onw.. also where is your try{}catch{} code around the `command.ExecuteNonQuery`  have you tried replacing the `using (var command = Connection.CreateCommand(sqlCmd, conn))` with `using (var command = new OleDbCommand())` setting the `command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;`  have you used the debugger to step through the code as well..? also why don't you create a Table name that makes more sense not based on some formatted utc date value..

Comment: Using `using (var command = new OleDbCommand())` makes no difference.  Yes, I have tried stepping through it and every time it hits `command.ExecuteNonQuery();` visual studio stops debugging (on my computer as well as everyone elses in my office).  I have a try catch around the larger chunk of code this is contained in... Which the catch is never tripped.  When I F10 (step over) the command.ExecuteNonQuery(); it crashes and stops debugging every time.  As far as the table name, I've set it to something fixed and it makes no difference.

Comment: *It makes a DBF file with only a few of my columns* The path is correct, it's actually making a DBF file that has SEVERITY and MESSAGE in it.  Why is Visual Studio crashing and not debugging.  Why is it not creating the additional 2 fields of STACKTRACE and OCCURRED?  I've changed the column names, that doesn't seem to change anything.  I've changed the connection / command style... No difference.

Comment: Updated question to reflect most recent changes.  No difference.  Still only creates the DBF with the first 2 fields and visual studio stops debugging upon stepping over the `command.ExecuteNonQuery()`.

Comment: No dice... I get `Syntax error in field definition.` with what you suggested.

Comment: have you tried giving field widths to your numeric and char fields

Comment: `"CREATE TABLE {0} ([SEVERITY] NUMERIC(2), [DETAILS] MEMO, [STACKTRACE] MEMO, [OCCURRED] CHAR(50))"` Same symptoms.  No difference.

Comment: what version of FoxPro are you using try to get the latest OLEDB Provider from here - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14839

Comment: if it's any consolation, I can remove the extended properties from the connectionstring and point it to an access database and your original code works by creating a table with all 4 fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that there is a max path length issue that the OleDB driver encounters upon creating the DBT file for the MEMO fields.  Shortening the path corrects the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because your are creating a table on just the date numerics.  You can't create a table such as "yyMMddHH" which might look like 16021715.  Try creating your table with a prefix of your log such as...

```
String.Format("CREATE TABLE Log{0} (etc.....", parm);
```

so the table name would actually become "Log16021715" and be a valid table name.

Comment: Changing the name to: `CREATE TABLE L16021721 ([SEVERITY] NUMERIC, [MESSAGE] MEMO, [STACKTRACE] MEMO, [OCCURRED] CHAR(50))` made no difference.  The issue is the same.

Comment: this should work for you .. why don't you try it without using the string.Format function This should work 
`CREATE TABLE L16021721 ([SEVERITY] NUMERIC, [MESSAGE] MEMO, [STACKTRACE] MEMO, [OCCURRED] CHAR(50))`

Comment: Was just about to come and say that Message is a reserved keyword in DBase according to [this](http://www.dbase.com/help/Local_SQL/IDH_LSQL_RESERVED.htm)

Comment: No difference.  Same "stops debugging" and the DBF has only 2 columns in it.

Comment: @VulgarBinary, let me ask you this... does it HAVE to be dBASE IV?  If not, I would strongly consider using Microsoft Visual Foxpro OleDB Adapter instead of jet.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14839   and Visual Foxpro is NOT Access, but .DBF,

Comment: @DRapp - Unfortunately this has to be natively supported with the .NET 4.5.2 install footprint.  This is installed sofware, thus DBase (which comes default installed).  I wish I didn't have to work in those constraints but it is what it is....  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

[VisualFoxPro CreateTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa977477(v=vs.71).aspx)

```
var currentLogTime = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyMMddHH");
protected const string FORMAT_CONNECTION_STRING = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=dBASE IV";

var connectionString = String.Format(FORMAT_CONNECTION_STRING, DBFPath);
Source="yourFilePathToSourceFile";Extended Properties=dBase IV";
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
using (OleDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    connection.Open();
    command.CommandText = String.Format("CREATE TABLE {0} (SEVERITY I, MESSAGE M, STACKTRACE M, OCCURRED C(50) NOCPTRANS"
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: This is dBASE IV, not access.